# Nginx rewrite to include folder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having a problem with my rewrite rule. It doesn't include folders in the rewrite path. For example:

`/randomstring/app.js` rewrites to `/var/www/CDN/Dev/App/app.js`

`/randomstring/dashboard/app.js` rewrites to `/var/www/CDN/Dev/App/app.js` but it should rewrite to `/var/www/CDN/Dev/App/dashboard/app.js`

I don't understand why it doesn't work. `(.*)` matches everything but a dot if I'm not mistaken so why doesn't it include the `dashboard/` part?

```
location ~* (css|js)$ {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)/(.*).(css|js)$ /$2.$3 ;
    root /var/www/CDN/Dev/App;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to use rewrite here. Alias should be enough

```
location ~* /[^/]+(/.+\.(css|js))$ {
    alias /var/www/CDN/Dev/App/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.+)\.(css|js)$ /$2.$3 ;
    root /var/www/CDN/Dev/App;
}
```